# Forms Recognizer Preview - can't load sample documents

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the Forms Recognizer preview, and after much trial and error, I finally got the documents to be read via the SAS URL. But, even with the sample documents that are provided in the Quick Start[1], I get the following response:

```
{
    "modelId": "d7ba79e3-38bc-4913-bb11-82656cb08adc",
    "trainingDocuments": [
        {
            "documentName": "Invoice_1.pdf",
            "pages": 1,
            "errors": [
                "Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits."
            ],
            "status": "failure"
        },
        {
            "documentName": "Invoice_2.pdf",
            "pages": 1,
            "errors": [
                "Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits."
            ],
            "status": "failure"
        },
        {
            "documentName": "Invoice_3.pdf",
            "pages": 1,
            "errors": [
                "Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits."
            ],
            "status": "failure"
        },
        {
            "documentName": "Invoice_4.pdf",
            "pages": 1,
            "errors": [
                "Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits."
            ],
            "status": "failure"
        },
        {
            "documentName": "Invoice_5.pdf",
            "pages": 1,
            "errors": [
                "Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits."
            ],
            "status": "failure"
        }
    ],
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorMessage": "Unable to fit model. No documents clustered."
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there something special that needs to happen on the BLOB storage side for these documents to be available?

I was getting this error message even on basic forms of our own, that fit well within the size constraints.

**Update**:
I think this is down to some problem in how I'm generating the SAS URL (of which the documentation is not clear at all). I have a storage account (SA), with a single container (C), containing all the PDF files within that.

Within the Azure Portal, I'm selecting the SA blade, then selecting Shared access signature, taking all the default selections, and then selecting **Generate SAS and connection string**. I tried taking the **Blob service SAS URL** value directly and passing that in the `source` field, but that gives the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "2024",
        "innerError": {
            "requestId": "77e73ba0-cbfe-4046-9730-beff8ec38be5"
        },
        "message": "Unable to list blobs on the Azure Blob storage account."
    }
}
```

I had to add `&comp=list&restype=container` to the `source`, and then the files are correctly listed, but with the errors above. Obviously something needs to be added to the SAS URL outside of what the Azure Potral generates, and what I added was only part of that.

I miss being able to send the document contents itself in a REST payload to train a model. :-(

[1] - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/blob/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample_data.zip

Comment: I'm getting an error "Train request is either invalid or missing required parameters. Please reference the API reference and retry your request." - was that something you encountered in your "much trial and error"? Just in case you can offer me any pointers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the name of the container in the blob to the SAS URL generated. example: "yourblobname.blob.core.windows.net/name of your container/rest of the sas url".

Comment: Please do not post links as answer. There will be a time where these links are not accessible anymore and your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Thanks! I restarted the process and this was actually the only change that was needed.

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered this problem because I didn't find the Quick Start documentation to be very clear - in fairness to Microsoft, this is partly because I'm inexperienced with generating SAS URLs in Azure and it is something that has improved very slightly since @iamsop raised a GitHub issue with them.

I made the following notes, which describe how I got it working. Hopefully they will help others in the future:

1. A blob storage container is required to dump the training documents
   in (go to Storage Accounts / {account name} / Blobs / + Container
   (give it a name and leave "Public access level" as "Private (no
   anonymous access)"
2. Click into the container and upload the training
   documents - all in the root folder, no sub folders (there can be a
   delay after the uploads say that they are complete before they are
   actually displayed within the container)
3. Create a shared access
   signature (SAS) for the blob container - start again at Storage
   Accounts / {account name} then don't go into Blobs, go into Shared
   access signature - the Allowed permissions only need to be Read and
   List, click "Generate SAS and connection string" and copy the "Blob
   service SAS URL"
4. Paste this URL into notepad (or whatever) and
   insert the name of the container before the query string
5. Now you may
   use commands such as

curl -X POST "{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/train" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}" --data-ascii "{'source': '{SAS url}'}"

- Replace "{endpoint}" with the provided API endpoint (may look something like https://region.api.cognitive.microsoft.com)
- Replace {subscription key} with the key available via the Form Reognizer resource overview tab
- Replace {SAS url} with the SAS URL generated above, the tweaked version that includes the container name

*(Note: My personal preference with the command above is to use single quotes within the "data-ascii" value rather than double quotes because then you don't need to escape them, making the command easier to read and to write)*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was doing everything other than modifying the SAS url to include the container name.

Answer (score 1):

How did you call the service? With a cURL command? Also, make sure your PDF files are directly in the Azure Blob container for which you got the shared access signature (no subfolders). The cURL command below worked for me:

curl -X POST "https://**Endpoint**/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/train" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: **Subscription Key**" --data-ascii "{ \"source\": \"**SAS URL**\"}"

Finally, make sure you are able to open the PDF files (i.e., check that they are not invalid).

Comment: Thanks. I must be doing something wrong with the SAS URL generation, as I had to manually modify it (add some parameters) to the URL before the Forms Recognizer service accepted it. I'll update my question with details of how I'm generating the SAS url.